# Cannot show Language settings link in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I configured SharePoint 2013 Server on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I want to configure for Languate settings.So I download and install ther SharePoint server language Pack for the following link.
http://www.microsoft.com/ja-JP/download/details.aspx?id=42543

However,the lanaguage setting link cannot display in my site's Site administration.

How can I do for this??

Please advice me.

Comment: Can you create a new site in that language?

Comment: I cannot Create except the default language.

Comment: Then something went wrong during installation of the language pack. After installation, you should be able to create sites in both default language (e.g. English) and your new language pack. Go to central admin -> upgrade and migration -> Check product and patch installation status. to check which language packs have been installed. Have you installed correct version, e.g. Server or Foundation?

Comment: I confirmed my sharepoint version as the following site.(http://blog.fpweb.net/how-to-find-your-sharepoint-version-in-ten-seconds-flat-with-powershell/). Version is SharePoint Foundation 2013,SharePoint Server 2013 Standard.What language pack version should install in my sharepoint server?I have already installed "Language Pack for SharePoint and Project Server 2013 - Japanese".

Comment: Should be fine. Did you run "SharePoint Configuration Wizard" (or psconfig from command line) after installation of language pack?